# Mediaelementjs video resume playback issues in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video

could use some help. We have a few Brightcove-hosted MP4 videos on our site. They're being displayed using Mediaelementjs's HTML5 video player with a Flash fallback.

**Here's the issue:** when a user pauses and resumes the video using the standard Mediaelementjs controls, the video doesn't always resume. Occasionally, it simply goes back to the start. This happens largely - but not always - when the video hasn't yet fully loaded. Oh, and only Chrome seems to be affected.

Now, the final spanner in the works is as follows: inspecting the videos in Chrome dev tools often gives us a "Inspected element has crashed" message, trashing the entire tab.

Any idea what could be causing this? Above all I'm stumped for ideas on how to debug the issue. i have already tried removing any conflicting scripts on the page, playing with the preload attribute, all to no avail.

```
<div class="mejs-mediaelement"><video id="foo" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" width="622" height="321" poster="foo">
<source id="foo" src="foo" type="video/mp4">
<object width="600" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" height="338" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="/js/mediaelement/flashmediaelement.swf" data="/js/mediaelement/flashmediaelement.swf">
    <param name="movie" value="/js/mediaelement/flashmediaelement.swf">
    <param name="flashvars" value="foo">
</object>
```

Comment: Any chance you could set us up with a publicly accessible html file which doesn't work? I might take a look in that case.

Comment: @Alex G give me 10mins with your codes ... ;) and ill help you out.

Answer (score 0):

In your mediaelement JS lib file, search for:

```
htmlMediaElement.canPlayType(mediaFiles[i].type).replace(/no/, '')
```

Change:

```
if (htmlMediaElement.canPlayType(mediaFiles[i].type).replace(/no/, '') !== '' 
    // special case for Mac/Safari 5.0.3 which answers '' to canPlayType('audio/mp3') but 'maybe' to canPlayType('audio/mpeg')
    || htmlMediaElement.canPlayType(mediaFiles[i].type.replace(/mp3/,'mpeg')).replace(/no/, '') !== '') {
```

To:

```
if (htmlMediaElement.canPlayType(mediaFiles[i].type).replace(/no|maybe/, '') !== '' 
    // special case for Mac/Safari 5.0.3 which answers '' to canPlayType('audio/mp3') but 'maybe' to canPlayType('audio/mpeg')
    || htmlMediaElement.canPlayType(mediaFiles[i].type.replace(/mp3/,'mpeg')).replace(/no|maybe/, '') !== '') {
```

Let me know if it worked for you.